# How to mask redirect subdomain and ports to another external subdomain on that same port

Tags: port, subdomain, redirection, mask

I have read through the forum but still cannot get a clear answer for what I need.
My purpose is to mask redirect a subdomain to another one with the port passing together.
For example, I want my vdi.mydomain.com:445566 redirect to other location at client.cloud.example.com:445566 (The port is the same)
Basically, I want to connect a RDP session to someone else's server on special port. I want to use my url instead of others. And I prefer mask the destination url if possible. I have all domain control on my side. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: This is just a simple DNS redirect. Port information is carried over.

Answer (score 0):

There is tree ways:

1. Create `vdi.mydomain.com CNAME client.cloud.example.com` or `vdi.mydomain.com A required IP addr` entry in your DNS.
2. Deploy proxy(e.g. haproxy) on vdi.mydomain.com:445566 and forward all requests to client.cloud.example.com:445566
3. Configure port forwarding on vdi.mydomain.com:445566 to forward all requests to client.cloud.example.com:445566

First one will not hide real IP address, second and third will hide real IP address.